# how to select a dynamic string from a sentence

Tags: javascript

How can I select the first number from these example sentences

```
"  1     SAMPLE SAMPLE 1"
"  20     SAMPLE SAMPLE 2"
```

I want to isolate the first number from those lines.

I tried a few string functions that come with javascript but can't seem to make them work. I don't want the spaces, I need the number only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var num = +/\d+/.exec("  1     SAMPLE SAMPLE 1")[0];
```

If you didn't need it converted to a number, then you can get rid of the first  `+`.

```
var num = /\d+/.exec("  1     SAMPLE SAMPLE 1")[0];
```

If you're not certain if there'll be a number, you'll want to get rid of the `[0]`, and extract the result after verifying.

```
var num = /\d+/.exec("       SAMPLE SAMPLE ");

if( num ) num = num[0];
```

Or since it's a number, you could convert it with `+` right from the Array.

```
if( num ) num = +num;
```

Comment: @s2xi: [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/AhYx3/5/) It isn't the final result you want, but it is closer. You were referencing a `text3` variable which didn't exist, and it seems that some of the elements did not find a number, so I did this from my answer `if( num ) num = num[0];` to ensure a match was found before trying to access `[0]`.

Comment: sorry this is the correct one http://jsfiddle.net/s2xi/AhYx3/7/ my problem is that i still get the ending number, if i did a replace(num, '') then it will remove the numbers in the array segments that have them . but if the number was present in an array segment where it needed it then it wouldn't be the correct approach. You see what Im saying?

Comment: @s2xi: I see what you're after. I've got something coming in a minute.

Comment: @s2xi: http://jsfiddle.net/AhYx3/8/ I think this is what you're after. It passes a function to `.replace()` that references memorized groups (or whatever you call them), and just builds the string inside the function.

Comment: Oh! I get the feeling im not all that creative ;) u are amazing! Kust curious but if I where to replace the spans with inputs using the variables as values how can I gice each input a name like field1...field2...field3....etc so I can save the results to ?a database

Comment: @s2xi: The `s1` parameter holds the number, so you'd probably just concatenate the number into the name attribute: `'<input type="text" name="field' + s1 + '">'`.

Comment: Oh hmm haha ya good point, I was just wondering for instances a number wasn't present. But thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = "  1     SAMPLE SAMPLE 1".match(/^\s*?(\d).*?$/)[1];
```